# AWS Lambda module initialization error: [Errno 30] Read-only file system

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, certificate

I have the following snippet in my python code to download AWS IoT topic certificates and keys which are stored in an S3 bucket.

```
 # download certs and keys
    certification_path = organisation + '/' + uuid + '/'
    
    client.download_file(BUCKET, certification_path + cert_file, cert_file)  # copy file to local storage  
    client.download_file(BUCKET, certification_path + key_file, key_file)
    client.download_file(BUCKET, certification_path + root_file, root_file)
```

The code runs perfectly in my AWS Cloud9 environment, but if I try to run the code as an AWS Lambda function, I get the error `module initialization error: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '-certificate.pem.crt.4aBBF198'`

How can I get past this error in order to obtain the correct certificates and publish messages to the IoT topic.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda only allows you to save into the `/tmp` directory.  I'd change to:

```
client.download_file(BUCKET, certification_path + cert_file, "/tmp/" + cert_file)
```

and so on.  Of course, whatever read these files now needs to know about the new path.

**EDIT**

If this is the Python IoT library there is a [specific call](https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-docs/html/index.html#AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib.AWSIoTMQTTClient.configureCredentials) to handle this.  You'd want to do something like:

```
client.download_file(BUCKET, certification_path + cert_file, '/tmp/' + cert_file)
client.download_file(BUCKET, certification_path + key_file, '/tmp/' + key_file)
client.download_file(BUCKET, certification_path + root_file, '/tmp/' + root_file)

iot_client.configureCredentials( '/tmp/' + root_file, '/tmp/' + key_file, '/tmp/' + cert_file)
```

before you tried to call anything else.

Comment: You're missing the trailing slash - use `/tmp/` so that the file name would be `/tmp/4db21849c5024ea25315448499c83e7d79cee59d2783c9aea91317b93ffdd47c-private.pem.key.04EfDEe2`

Comment: sorry, wrong error! I meant to show this error message ```module initialization error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/task/4db21849c5024ea25315448499c83e7d79cee59d2783c9aea91317b93ffdd47c-certificate.pem.crt'
```

Comment: And that is the second part - now that the certificate is not in the current directory you need to change *that* code to read from `/tmp`.  See the update to my answer.

Comment: I had seen this on the AWSIoTPythonSDK documentation that you sent in and previously tried it but got the error ```'S3' object has no attribute 'configureCredentials'```. I assumed I was doing something wrong

Comment: It was difficult to tell from your code - that method should be called on your `AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib.AWSIoTMQTTClient`, not your S3Client as pointed to in my link.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Can you post some code?  Where are you getting the `No such file or directory` error?

Comment: I have included me code in its entirety, to hopefully help give a better idea of what I am trying to achieve. I am getting the ```No such file or directory``` at this point in the code ```client.download_file(BUCKET, certification_path + cert_file, "/tmp/" + cert_file)```